# VTK (Activiz) rendering differently on different hardware

Tags: c#, vtk

I am using Activiz.NET to render some STLs in a C# tool. The renderwindow and renderer settings are as follows.

```
window.SetMultiSamples(0);
window.SetAlphaBitPlanes(1);
renderer.SetOcclusionRatio(0.1);
renderer.SetUseDepthPeeling(1);
```

Running the tool on an STL on my system results in the following image (which is as expected).

[image: Expected image result on my system.] (Click image for full size)

However, when two of my colleagues run the same tool on the exact same STL, they get the following image as output.

[image: Rendering artefacts on two other systems.] (Click image for full size)

Could these artefacts be related to different hardware of our three systems? Does anyone have a solution that would ensure that the render quality is always the same on all systems?

Comment: It's possible that there are differences in regard to the 3D settings, such as Antialiasing, Transparency Antialiasing and Filtering. Have you checked the respective control panels (Catalyst Control Center for AMD, NVIDIA Control Panel for NVIDIA) for such settings?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tested it on three laptops with an AMD graphics card (different types) and two desktop PCs with an NVIDIA graphics card (also different types). All three AMD laptops show the artefacts, while the NVIDIA desktops do not. I am currently writing a small tool that just shows a couple of transparent meshes to see if that does render well on all systems.

Comment: Do you use vtkSmartVolumeMapper ? Because this object "know" the hardware resource, and behave a little bit different ...

Comment: No, I do not use vtkSmartVolumeMapper. Might it have something to do with the fact that Activiz.NET is based on VTK 5.8 instead of the latest VTK 7.0?

Comment: I have been able to test it on an NVIDIA laptop now as well and no artefacts are visible there. The VTK FAQ also confirms that there are some issues with AMD cards (although it does not detail which issues). http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/FAQ#What_Graphics_Cards_work_with_VTK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two years, I finally figured out the problem. The artefacts were only present on systems that had both onboard graphics and a dedicated GPU. On some of these systems, the the tool did not automatically make use of the GPU, but used the onboard graphics for rendering instead. Forcing the tool to use the GPU in the GPU settings resolved this.